# how wrench plugin is useful for in gulp

Tags: gulp

I was learning gulp. I had come thru following code.

```
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});
```

Can somebody help me to understand what above code is useful for?

Answer (score 5):

This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory in order to load all gulp tasks, so you dont have to manually import new gulp tasks, just create whatevergulptask.js inside '/gulp' directory and you can use it from the command line.

Another advange of doing it like this is that you dont have a huge gulpfile.js with millions of tasks and lines of code, as instead you have a whatevergulptask.js per TASK, just a good practice cos the gulpfile grows pretty fast

Example gulpfile.js

```
 /**
 *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
 *  The gulp tasks are splitted in several files in the gulp directory
 *  because putting all here was really too long
 */

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function (file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function (file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
 */

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

YOUR FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
gulp/

    build.js
    whatevergulptask.js
    ...
```

Comment: Just FYI, as this cost me half a day (and is still relevant as independent from wrench):
/someRegExp/i.test(...) is the same const re = RegExp('someRegExp', 'i'); re.test(...). I prefer the latter, as it's clearer!
The parameter (or suffix) "i" just enables "ignoreCase". 
so, it could be left out, if you're sure that all your file extensions are lower case.

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase